# how to format a date from an existing dateformat

Tags: javascript, date, format

How can i format a date in javascript?

```js
let date = '2022-01-01';
let fd = date.toLocaleString("nl-NL"); // in dutch format
alert(fd); // outputs also 2022-01-01; should be 01-01-2022
```

Comment: `"aaaa".toLocaleString("nl-NL")`. Your `date` is not in fact a `Date`

Comment: it should be .toLocaleDateString('nl-NL') -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: `new Date('2022-01-01').toLocaleDateString("nl-NL");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not constructing a [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) object.

```js
const date = new Date('2022-01-01')
let fd = date.toLocaleString("nl-NL");
//or make it by yourself
//let fd = date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getFullYear()
console.log(fd);
```

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score -1):

```js
let date = '2022-01-01';
var options = {year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric"};
fd = (new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-AU", options).format(new Date(date))).replace(/\//g, '-');
alert(fd);
```

try this.

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)